# StackOverflowException after adding entity when sitting at a window asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing an application that will allow DBAs to view/add/edit/delete server information from a database.  I am fairly new to asp.net mvc, but am trying to follow best practices.

I started database first and generated a model using visual studio.  I then generated a view based on this model, again using visual studio.  Everything works great and it displays exactly how I want it to.  The weirdness comes in when I try to add an entity.  When I add an entity and save it in the database, it returns properly and displays the new server in the list.  After about 5-10 seconds, the application crashes with a System.StackOverflowException.  If I close the application and re-open it and navigate to the server view again, it will again crash after 5-10 seconds.

I have single stepped through the code that adds the entity, and it everything is set properly and the entity is added and the database saved.

If I manually remove this entity from the database, and load up the application again - nothing.  Works perfectly fine.

Here is my code to add a server:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string serverAlias = collection["ServerAlias"];
        string domain = collection["Domain"];
        string instanceName = collection["InstanceName"];
        string location = collection["Location"];
        string edition = collection["Edition"];
        Nullable<System.DateTime> lastUpdated = null;


        SQLServer toAdd = new SQLServer()
        {
           ServerAlias = serverAlias,
           Domain = domain,
           InstanceName = instanceName,
           Location = Convert.ToByte(location),
           LastUpdated = lastUpdated,
           SQLServerEdition = Convert.ToByte(edition)
        };
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _ServerDB.SQLServers.Add(toAdd);
                _ServerDB.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //will add more robust error handling later
            return Content("Failed to add server");
        }
    }
```

It should be noted that Location and SQLServerEdition above are foreign key IDs.

I have single stepped this code and ensured that the proper values are being set for each value.  This is confirmed for the first few moments that the server list displays again, before the StackOverflowException explosion that is.

Below is the definition of the SQLServer model.

```
public partial class SQLServer
{
    public short ServerID { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name="Server Alias")]
    public string ServerAlias { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public byte SQLServerEdition { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Location { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual Edition Edition { get; set; }
    public virtual ServerLocation ServerLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

Edit:  Here's the view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MSSQL_Server_Viewer.Models.SQLServer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Server Index";
}
<br />
<br />

<label>@ViewBag.Title</label>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Server", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServerAlias)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstanceName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Domain)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Edition.Edition1)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServerLocation.Location)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ServerAlias)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InstanceName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Domain)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Edition.Edition1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ServerLocation.Location)
    </td>
    <td>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ServerID })
                </td>
                <td> | </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ServerID })
                </td>
                <td> | </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ServerID })
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Are you working in mvc or web forms? Why the partial class if in mvc? And why so much initialization before determining if the model is valid?

Comment: @nocturns2 Hey Nocturns, I am working in MVC, the partial class was produced by entity framework.  I suppose that the initialization should wait till after the model validation, but that is concerning form.  None of your points seem to be addressing the issue at hand, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Initially, I was assessing that you are in fact using mvc. Then I questioned, why wouldn't you check the ModelState.IsValid before initializing all of properties for SQLServer model. Why I even mentioned it was, I was wondering if the initialization is happening smoothly, without error.

Comment: Yes, everything goes properly and the data is entered into the database

Comment: Is Edition.Edition1 the right spelling? (in the View)

Comment: @nocturns2  Yes.  The class was generated by Visual Studio, as was the view.  As I stated in the post, I have single stepped this code and everything is set properly and it is inserted into the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103880/discussion-between-aserian-and-nocturns2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching for this later - I found the solution.  It was not what/where I expected it to be and such a small error.

In the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ServerID })
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ServerID })
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ServerID })
    </td>
<tr>
```

The last "tr" was meant to be a closing "/tr"

I'm not too familiar with HTML, so I'm not entirely certain why this didn't just throw a syntactical error.  Such a small bug, and caused me days of grief.  I hope the next person to stumble along this finds the issue quicker than I did.